# Java ImageReader Returns No Images

Tags: java, image-processing, metadata

I've been reading up on SO and Oracle throughout the day to learn how to extract metadata from a .jpg image (extracting GPS data embedded in am image).  I am in an environment where I don't have a lot of options for 3rd party libraries.

I stumbled across the ImageIO, ImageReader, IIOMetadata combination but am having problems:

```
    File file = new File("/home/djtorrey/Pictures/test.jpg");
    System.out.println(file.isFile());
    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);

    Iterator readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpg");
    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader)readers.next();

    reader.setInput(iis,true);
    int value = reader.getNumImages(false);
    System.out.println(value);
```

This is the code that I am testing right now.  As you can see I am creating a file object pointing to the image, verifying that it sees it as a file (it does), and then creating an ImageInputStream based upon the file.  I've verified that it is not corrupt by pushing the file into a BufferedImage object and reading data from it.

I grab the ImageReader for a jpg, set the ImageReader input to the ImageInputStream, and then check the number of images it sees.

I should be seeing 1 representing the one image I am pointing to, but it keeps returning a -1, indicating there are no images.

BLUF: What am I doing wrong in the above code that it is not properly seeing the image I am pointing to?

Comment: Does `reader.getNumImages(true)` return a different value?

Comment: **the return value -1 just indicates that a search is necessary to determine the number of remaining images in the stream**: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html#getNumImages(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html#getNumImages(boolean))

Comment: @Gilfoy thanks, i'll check it out quick

Comment: @Gilfoy looks like I missed that tidbit, it seems to work.  If you throw it in an answer i'll be more than happy to credit you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the return value -1 just indicates that a search is necessary to determine the number of remaining images in the stream: [ImageReader Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html#getNum%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BImages(boolean))